# How to align form in the center, but have the label above the very left of the input

Tags: html, css, forms, position

I thought "hey, let's practice just 10 minutes with forms before bed..." Yeah...it's been an hour and I can't figure it out!

I want all to be centered, except for the label, I want it to be above the input, on the very left. and of course, if I resize the window I want it to "follow" the input, otherwise I could just adjust the position in px.

How can I do it? Thank you very much!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, deepskyblue, pink);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.space:focus {
  outline-color: black;
}

.space {
  width: 300px;
}

.submit {
  width: 30vw;
  align-self: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgb(255,105,200), aqua);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
  <div class="form1">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="space" type="text" id="name"><br><br>


      <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      <input class="space" type="email" id="email"><br><br>

      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="space placeholder" name="name" rows="8" cols="50" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Write your message here'"></textarea><br>

      <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks centered in this little window when I run the code snippet, but if you make it "Full page" you'll see it's not :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wanted this result?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, deepskyblue, pink);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form1 label {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.space:focus {
  outline-color: black;
}

.space {
  /*width: 300px;*/
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.submit {
  /*width: 30vw;*/
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgb(255,105,200), aqua);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="form1">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input class="space" type="text" id="name"><br><br>


      <label for="email">E-mail</label>
      <input class="space" type="email" id="email"><br><br>

      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea class="space placeholder" name="name" rows="8" cols="50" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Write your message here'"></textarea><br>

      <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
```

Comment: yes! thank you! so you added width 100% on label and input? How come this makes them be centered?

Comment: hi. in addition to the width of 100%, I also prescribed a max-width of 300 pixels. and the centering also happened due to the align-items rule.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add some css to the label, as you have provided input with a width of 300, give the same to label and it works.

```css
.form1 {
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, deepskyblue, pink);
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 50px 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: helvetica;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.form1 label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 300px;
}

.space:focus {
  outline-color: black;
}

.space {
  width: 300px;
}

.submit {
  width: 30vw;
  align-self: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, rgb(255,105,200), aqua);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="form1">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="space" type="text" id="name"><br><br>


    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input class="space" type="email" id="email"><br><br>

    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea class="space placeholder" name="name" rows="8" cols="50" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Write your message here'"></textarea><br>

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
  </div>
```